# Transform all text links into actual links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I transform all text links in a page into actual links?

For example, I want to change all text links like this:

```
<p>http://www.google.com</p>
```

or in a table like this:

```
<td>http://www.google.com</td>
```

into this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>
```

and this:

```
<td><a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a></td>
```

Comment: Why do you have pages with addresses that are not hyperlinks?

Comment: @LeeTaylor, you have never seen this before?  For example what about a blog page where someone pastes in a hyperlink and you want to automatically link it.  I think this is a really good question and does not deserve a down vote.

Comment: @Jessemon Yes, of course. I was asking to try to elicit some more information on how much control the OP has on the content within his pages.

Comment: @LeeTaylor. Okay cool. I think it is a good idea to make the hyperlinks on the server-side if possible.  :D

Comment: @Jessemon - Exactly, that's what I was trying to allude to...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace plain URLs with links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function createLinks(){
      $('p, td').filter(function() {
        return this.innerHTML.match(/(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?/);
      }).each(function(){
        var link = $('<a>', { href: this.innerHTML,
                              text: this.innerHTML });

        if(this.tagName == "P")
          this.parentNode.replaceChild(link[0], this);
        else{
          this.removeChild(this.childNodes[0])
          this.appendChild(link[0]);
        }
      });
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#create_links').click(function(){
        createLinks();
      });
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    a{
      display:block;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>This shouldn't became a link</p>
  <p>http://www.thisshouldbecamealink.com</p>
  <p>http://www.anotherlink.com</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Not a link</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>http://www.validlink.com</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button id="create_links">Create links</button>
</body>
</html>
```